# Passing a value using onPress from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on an app and I want to pass in a key from a dictionary to a child screen. I have the dictionary in the parent, the code below shows what I want to accomplish

```js
import ImageDetail from "../components/ImageDetail";

    var Salad = {
        GreekSalad: ["Greek Salad", "Romaine lettuce, cucumber, onion, olives, tomatoes, bell peppers, feta cheese dressed with lemon, salt, and olive oil dressing",require('../../assets/greeksalad.jpg'), 10],
        ArabicSalad: ["Arabic Salad", "Diced cucumbers, tomato, green onion, parsley dressed with lemon, salt, and olive oil dressing",require('../../assets/arabicsalad.jpg'), 8],
        Tabula: ["Tabouli", "fine chopped parsley, cracked wheat, tomatoes, and cucumber dressed with lemon salt and olive oil dressing", 8],
        KHSS: ["KH Special Salad", "Romaine lettuce, cucumbers, onions, tomatoes, onions, apples, mint, bell peppers, sunflower seeds, and zaatar dressed with lemon, salt, and olive oil dressing", 12],
        LSCup: ["Lentil Soup", "Flavorful lentil, carrot, and onion pureed soup(Cup 8oz)", 5],
        LSBowl: ["Lentil Soup", "Flavorful lentil, carrot, and onion pureed soup(Bowl 12oz)", 7]
    
    };
```

The next portion of the code is the part that is difficult for me to finish, specifically the `TouchableOpacity` passing the Salads. `GreekSalad` key and value into the next page

```js
    const Salads = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.backGround}>
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <Image style={styles.logostyle} source={require('../../assets/KabobHouseLogo.jpg')}/>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>Salads{"\n"}</Text>    
                        <View style={styles.container1}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={(Salad.GreekSalad) => {props.navigation.navigate("InnerMenu")}}>
                            <ImageDetail title={Salad.GreekSalad[0]} description={Salad.GreekSalad[1]} imageSource={Salad.GreekSalad[2]} price={Salad.GreekSalad[3]}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                            <ImageDetail title={Salad.ArabicSalad[0]} description={Salad.ArabicSalad[1]} imageSource={Salad.ArabicSalad[2]} price={Salad.ArabicSalad[3]}/>
                            <ImageDetail title={Salad.Tabula[0]}  description={Salad.Tabula[1]}  imageSource={require('../../assets/KabobHouseLogo.jpg')}      price={Salad.Tabula[2]}/>
                            <ImageDetail title={Salad.KHSS[0]}  description={Salad.KHSS[1]}  imageSource={require('../../assets/KabobHouseLogo.jpg')} price={Salad.KHSS[2]}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **how you pass values** in React Navigation to the next screen

```js
// navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })
const nextScreen = ()=>{
    props.navigation.navigate("InnerMenu",{saladKey:Salad.GreekSalad[1]})
}
```

Then pass the function into `onPress`

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={nextScreen}>
   <ImageDetail title={Salad.GreekSalad[0]} description={Salad.GreekSalad[1]} imageSource={Salad.GreekSalad[2]} price={Salad.GreekSalad[3]}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is **how you access them** in the next screen

```js
const childScreen = (props)=>{
  const saladKey = props.route.params.saladKey;
}
```

Lastly I recommended that you don't make a habit of passing around values between screens. Instead for most cases you can use a thing called `useContext` which lets you share state between all your screens. Read more here (https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/)